# Issue in applying template recursively in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am new to XPath and XSLT. I am writing an XSLT which is applying template recursively whenever it finds any 'complexType' as type attribute in input.

Please note that the logic of identifying complex type is working fine so I am not bothered about that.

Below is my XML Schema input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType name="Object1">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="segment-1" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="segment-2" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="complexType1" type="anyComplexType" />
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="anyComplexType">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="complexType2" type="anotherComplexType" />
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="anyComplexType">
        <xs:all>
            <some Element>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

and this is the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.approuter.com/schemas/cdk/api/">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" xml:space="preserve" method="xml" />

    <xsl:variable name="ObjectType" select=" 'Object1' " />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="object">
            <xsl:attribute name="name" select="$ObjectType" />
            <xsl:attribute name="label" select="$ObjectType" />
            <xsl:attribute name="minCount">1</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="maxCount">1</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//*:complexType[@name = $ObjectType]" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*:complexType">
        <!-- Logic to fing complexType' goes here -->
        <xsl:call-template name="Elements" />   
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="Elements">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//*:complexType[@name =@type]" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Explaining the flow below:

1. XSLT starts reading input from root.
2. Create Object Element and then apply another template (ComplexTypeTemplate) having complextype name as Object1.
3. ComplexType template is performing some logic to identify the complexType as type attribute and then calling another template named 'Element'.
4. Element template is again calling complexType template for applying same logic for complexType type.

Step 4 is not working for me. I believe there is some XPath pattern or path issue in this.

Comment: Would it be possible to show the output you expect in this case? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Pooja. If you log on again, please consider accepting the answer below. To do so, click the tick mark to the left of the answer, to mark the question as resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem occurs in this line:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//*:complexType[@name = @type]" />
```

You are looking for any `xs:complexType` whose `name` attribute matches its own `@type` attribute. But there are no `xs:complexType` elements which even have  `type` attribute.

It is the `xs:element` that has the `type` attribute, but when you do the `xsl:apply-templates` you are positioned on a `xs:complexType` element. Calling a named template doesn't change your context.

To fix this, you could change your named template `Elements` to include code to select the `element` elements. You would also need to use the `current()` function to refer to your current context (the `element` rather than the `complexType` you are trying to select)

```
<xsl:template name="Elements">
    <xsl:for-each select="*/*:element">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//*:complexType[@name = current()/@type]" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

It may be better to do away with the named template though, and use a template match instead. Try this XSLT

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.approuter.com/schemas/cdk/api/">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" xml:space="preserve" method="xml" />

    <xsl:variable name="ObjectType" select=" 'Object1' " />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="object">
            <xsl:attribute name="name" select="$ObjectType" />
            <xsl:attribute name="label" select="$ObjectType" />
            <xsl:attribute name="minCount">1</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="maxCount">1</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//*:complexType[@name = $ObjectType]" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*:complexType">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*:element" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*:element">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//*:complexType[@name = current()/@type]" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that, it might actually be better to use an `xsl:key` to look up the `complexType` records. Try this XSLT too

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.approuter.com/schemas/cdk/api/">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" xml:space="preserve" method="xml" />
    <xsl:key name="complexType" match="*:complexType" use="@name" />

    <xsl:variable name="ObjectType" select=" 'Object1' " />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="object">
            <xsl:attribute name="name" select="$ObjectType" />
            <xsl:attribute name="label" select="$ObjectType" />
            <xsl:attribute name="minCount">1</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="maxCount">1</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('complexType', $ObjectType)" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*:complexType">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*:element" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*:element">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('complexType', @type)" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```